# How to connect Arduino and Android to the same server?

Tags: android, azure, parse-platform, arduino, server

I am making a project and I need to get data from the Arduino to a server (I don't have a server), and the read this data from an Android. And the same on the other way (from Android -> to the server -> to the Arduino).

I newbie to dealing with servers. I am trying to figure out which server to use (I need to save a database on it also...). I know this one:
[www.parse.com](http://www.parse.com)
and I have read about Microsoft azure.

How can I choose with which one should I work? where can I start from to read about this?
and if you have suggestions for a free server, I would be glad if you tell about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many variables that go into the decision of what services you will need. Microsoft has a suite of IoT products that can get you going.

Here are some great resources to get you started on the Azure IoT suite. Take the time to read through and figure out which services you need.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/scenarios/internet-of-things/

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-67

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing you need to consider with the server is the kind of data you will be collecting and how you want to store it. As far as being able to connect to the server with both Arduino and Android, any service you choose will be able to be accessed by both platforms.

Azure is a good option because there are a lot of pre-built solutions that you can modify. You can find a high level description of different solutions [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/get-started/).

Comment: everyone likes free :) but unfortunately there is nothing as such, but there are cheaper storage services like Azure Storage. If you're learning I would recommend the Azure Free trial available here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/offers/ms-azr-0044p/

Comment: thank you. but my arduino is mega 2560, Azure have SDK for arduino YUN, do you know if this can work well too?

Comment: You can always leverage SMTP protocol and email the info to an inbox. From there your android takes control. This is easily implemented with a gmail account. All depends on how the data is consumed on the android end.

Comment: but I need every time when my arduino send data to the server (gmail !?), then all the android devices receives this data immediately. I am not sure it can be implemented with a gmail account, correct me if I am wrong!